# How to decode Core DB Account.Signers using the stellar js-sdk

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk

In the recent core v10.3, there is a new base64 encoded column in the accounts table in the core db which replaces the signers table in earlier core versions. How can I decode this column to produce a backwards compatible array:

```
[{publicKey, weight}]
```

using the js sdk?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var StellarBase = require('stellar-base');
var jsxdr = require('js-xdr');

let signers = new jsxdr.VarArray(StellarBase.xdr.Signer, 20)
  .fromXDR('AAAAAQAAAAC+GwdMJxaEbnW0z0RP6jJvTg+s8mjVw7+wPpJEbZAJdQAAAAo=', 'base64');

for (signer of signers) {
  console.log(signer.key());
  console.log(signer.weight());
}
```

Please note that the column will be `NULL` when there are no signers added to the account.